# cancellable F# async main with exceptions propagated

Tags: f#, .net-core, f#-async

I am looking for a solution like F# `Async.Start`, but not have it swallow exceptions. I want the console application to die normally with an unhandled exception. It is a .NET Core 2.1 app that I need to dispose of resources by responding to Linux SIGTERM and SIGINT signals. How do I modify this code so that it will propagate the `kaboom!` exception?

```ml
let mainAsync() =
    async {
        // blow up on purpose after a number of seconds
        let seconds = 10
        printfn "%d seconds and counting" seconds
        do! (System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(float seconds)).TotalMilliseconds |> int |> Async.Sleep

        //failwithf "kaboom!"
        // Update: failwithf does reproduce the problem
        // My real app is making WCF calls that are Task based and awaiting on them
        // I don't know how to make a small test case for this
        // The client is throwing a TimeoutException if unable to connect

        wcfClient.RetrieveServiceContentAsync someValue |> Async.AwaitTask
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    use cancelMainAsync = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
    use cancelMain = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false)
    let cancel() =
        if not cancelMainAsync.IsCancellationRequested then
            cancelMainAsync.Cancel()
            cancelMain.Set() |> ignore
    System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.add_Unloading(fun _ -> cancel())
    System.Console.CancelKeyPress.Add (fun keyPress -> keyPress.Cancel <- true; cancel())
    Async.Start(mainAsync(), cancelMainAsync.Token)
    cancelMain.WaitOne() |> ignore
    0
```

Comment: Doesn't `Async.RunSynchronously` work for you?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I don't think so. The `ctrl+c` does not trigger the `CancelKeyPress` event..

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. When I run this and don't cancel it blows up with error code `-532462766` not `0`. When I hit *ctrl-c* it cancels out without throwing kaboom. What are you worried about it swallowing?

Comment: @DevonBurriss you are right. Looks like the above test case isn't good enough. My real app is a making a WCF call that is throwing a `System.TimeoutException` exception that appears to be swallowed by `Async.Start` and the app never exits. Let me see if I can add more too it to reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Fyodor mentioned in the comments, I think just using `Async.RunSynchronously` will do the trick.  This little version of your code I put together seems to print "Cancelled" when I hit CTRL+C, and it throws the "Kaboom!" exception when I don't:

```
open System
open System.Threading

let f () = 
    async {
        printfn "Running..."
        do! Async.Sleep 10000
        failwith "Kaboom!"
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    use cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource()
    Console.CancelKeyPress |> Event.add (fun _ -> cancellation.Cancel(); printfn "Cancelled")
    Async.RunSynchronously(f(), cancellationToken = cancellation.Token)
    0
```

**EDIT**

Screenshot demonstrating termination upon CTRL+C.  Note the extra `printfn` after `Async.RunSynchronously` in this version, and how it does not execute.

[image]

Comment: It does print "Cancelled" when I hit ctrl+c, but it doesn't exit.

Comment: That's because your Async computation doesn't have any way to stop. It should take the cancellation token and watch it, and stop when signaled.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Do you have an example?

Comment: @CameronTaggart I see the program terminate immediately when I hit CTRL+C.  This should work because the `CancellationToken` is provided to `Async.RunSynchronously`, so it terminates when `Cancel` is called.  I've edited the post to include a screenshot demonstrating that it exits immediately when CTRL+C is pressed.  Perhaps this is a difference with running on Windows vs Linux?

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach I see that now too on the command line. When I ran it from Visual Studio, it left the command window open unlike other solutions. I captured some screenshots here: https://github.com/ctaggart/blog/issues/3 I'll try with the real app that throws the WCF errors later today.

Comment: It is indeed working fine with `Async.RunSynchronously`, passing in the `CancellationTokenSource`. Marking this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I need to make it to tomorrow, so here is the solution I came up with. The F# Async interop with C# Async can be very frustrating at times like these. Please review. I'd be happy if there was a better solution.

I ended up passing my own exception handler to `Async.StartWithContinuations`, but since it starts on the same thread, I added `do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()` to `mainAsync`. That allows `CancelKeyPress` to work. If you don't need `CancelKeyPress`, no need to put it on another thread.

A primary goal is to make sure some precious resources are disposed of correctly. "safe haven" will get printed when an exception occurs, the console app is cancelled with ctrl+c or killed. From Visual Studio, you can kill the app by hitting the close button on the console window that pops up when running. The exit code gets set differently for exceptions and for being cancelled.

```ml
let mainAsync() =
    async {
        do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()

        use precious = { new System.IDisposable with override this.Dispose() = printfn "safe haven" }

        // blow up on purpose after a number of seconds
        let seconds = 10
        printfn "%d seconds and counting" seconds
        do! (System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(float seconds)).TotalMilliseconds |> int |> Async.Sleep
        failwithf "kaboom!"

        // the real app is has a System.TimeoutException being thrown from a C# Task
        //wcfClient.RetrieveServiceContentAsync someValue |> Async.AwaitTask
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let mutable exitCode = 0
    use cancelMainAsync = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
    use cancelMain = new System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim()

    let cancel() =
        if not cancelMainAsync.IsCancellationRequested then
            cancelMainAsync.Cancel()
            cancelMain.Set()

    let exceptionHandler (ex: System.Exception) =
        let ex =
            match ex with
            | :? System.AggregateException as ae ->
                if ae.InnerExceptions.Count = 1 then ae.InnerException else ex
            | _ -> ex
        printfn "%A" ex
        exitCode <- 1
        cancel()

    System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.add_Unloading(fun _ -> cancel())
    System.Console.CancelKeyPress.Add (fun args -> args.Cancel <- true; exitCode <- 2; cancel())
    Async.StartWithContinuations(mainAsync(), (fun _ -> ()), exceptionHandler, (fun _ -> ()), cancelMainAsync.Token)
    cancelMain.Wait()
    exitCode
```

### Update with Solution

Aaron insisted that `Async.RunSchronously` works with the `CancellationToken` and it does. I marked his answer as the solution. This will blow up just like I wanted, except for the `OperationCancelException`.

```ml
open System

let mainAsync() =
    async {
        use precious = { new System.IDisposable with override this.Dispose() = printfn "safe haven" }
        // blow up on purpose after a number of seconds
        let seconds = 10
        printfn "%d seconds and counting" seconds
        do! (System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(float seconds)).TotalMilliseconds |> int |> Async.Sleep
        failwithf "kaboom!"
        // the real app is has a System.TimeoutException being thrown from a C# Task
        //wcfClient.RetrieveServiceContentAsync someValue |> Async.AwaitTask
        return 0
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let cancellation = new Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
    let cancel() =
        if not cancellation.IsCancellationRequested then
            cancellation.Cancel()

    Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.add_Unloading(fun _ -> cancel())
    Console.CancelKeyPress.Add (fun event -> event.Cancel <- true; cancel())
    Async.RunSynchronously(mainAsync(), cancellationToken = cancellation.Token)
```

### Update Solution with a bit more Exception Handling

For completeness, here is the additional exception handling added back in.

```ml
open System

let mainAsync() =
    async {
        use precious = { new System.IDisposable with override this.Dispose() = printfn "safe haven" }
        // blow up on purpose after a number of seconds
        let seconds = 10
        printfn "%d seconds and counting" seconds
        do! (System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(float seconds)).TotalMilliseconds |> int |> Async.Sleep
        failwithf "kaboom!"
        // the real app is has a System.TimeoutException being thrown from a C# Task
        //wcfClient.RetrieveServiceContentAsync someValue |> Async.AwaitTask
        return 0
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let cancellation = new Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
    let cancel() =
        if not cancellation.IsCancellationRequested then
            cancellation.Cancel()

    Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.add_Unloading(fun _ -> cancel())
    Console.CancelKeyPress.Add (fun event -> event.Cancel <- true; cancel())

    try
        Async.RunSynchronously(mainAsync(), cancellationToken = cancellation.Token)
    with
    | :? OperationCanceledException -> 2
    | ex ->
        let ex =
            match ex with
            | :? AggregateException as ae ->
                if ae.InnerExceptions.Count = 1 then ae.InnerException else ex
            | _ -> ex
        printfn "%A" ex
        1
```

Comment: A minor update on the updates. I changed it to `let cancellation` instead of `use cancellation` to avoid a `System.ObjectDisposedException: The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed` on exceptions because of the `add_Unloading`.

Comment: The `do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()` wasn't necessary in mainAsync with this updated solution, so removed it.

Comment: This last solution is the first thing that I tried that works, I'd give you 1000 if I could